# xcode - Embedded Binary Validation Error with OneSignal Target for Distribution

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I've used GoNative to generate an application that I am using OneSignal with for push notifications.  I've been able to follow all the steps, and test the iOS application with a developer provisioning profile and that has worked fine.

I'm now attempting to get the application to a point where I can upload it for approval, and I'm getting a "Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the parent app." error.  Looking at the details, the Embedded Binary Signing Certificate is pointing to a "iPhone Developer..." certificate while the Parent App Signing Certificate is pointing to the "iPhone Distribution..."

I currently have the parent app signed with a Distribution Provisioning Profile that has a Distribution Certificate.  For the OneSignal target I'm using the "Automatically Manage Signing" option, but the only teams it has presented are a Personal Team, and a Team for my workplace, neither of which share the same 10 digit code that the Parent Signing has.

I have looked through several other questions and validated that my Keychain trust is set to "Use System Defaults".  I've tried new provisioning profiles but the team never seems to be able to change to match the primary signing.

Is there any suggestions for a course of action to resolve this?  I'm brand new to app development in general, let alone working on a Mac so I'm not ruling out something obvious that doesn't get called out in other questions.